# Correlation Matrix Between Two Dataframes in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix-multiplication

I have two [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe)s:

**dataframe1**

```
name1 500
name2 394
name3 344
...
name2000 300
```

**dataframe2**

```
name1 200
name2 194
name3 44
...
name2000 100
```

And an empty 2000X2000 matrix (`empty.matrix`)

What I want is to fill this matrix with correlation values between the two [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe)s. So that the first element in `df1` will have a correlation value with every element of `df2`... up until `element 2000`. I am doing this through the following code:

```
for (i in 1:2000) {
  for (j in 1:2000){ 
    empty.matrix[i,j] <- cor(df1$V1[[i]],df2$V2[[j]])
    }
}
```

**Problem is, this is taking forever.  Anybody have a quicker way of getting this through?** Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are calculating the correlation between two values, which will return `NA`.

Answer (score 3):

assuming that your data frames have the same number of rows, the following code should work:

```
cor(dataframe1, dataframe2)
```

Here is an example using the `mtcars` data set in R:

```
cor(mtcars[1:5], mtcars[6:11])
         wt        qsec         vs         am       gear       carb
mpg  -0.8676594  0.41868403  0.6640389  0.5998324  0.4802848 -0.5509251
cyl   0.7824958 -0.59124207 -0.8108118 -0.5226070 -0.4926866  0.5269883
disp  0.8879799 -0.43369788 -0.7104159 -0.5912270 -0.5555692  0.3949769
hp    0.6587479 -0.70822339 -0.7230967 -0.2432043 -0.1257043  0.7498125
drat -0.7124406  0.09120476  0.4402785  0.7127111  0.6996101 -0.090789
```